# Connecting two PCs through TCP using C#

Tags: c#, ip, tcpclient, tcpserver

I'm trying to establish a TCP connection between two PCs (mine & friend's). Now, I know that the logic is very simple but I want to check if the connection is successful. 
The friend of mine starts the server and gives me the IP address via whatismyip.com, but when I enter that IP I get the timeout error.
I'm not quite sure that this is the right way of establishing the connection to PC in another LAN. Will be glad for any help \ advises \ external links.
Below is my code:

```
internal class Server
{
    private TcpListener m_server;
    private readonly int m_port = 8888;

    public void Start()
    {
        try
        {
            m_server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, m_port);
            m_server.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("Server started");

            while(true)
            {
                TcpClient client = m_server.AcceptTcpClient();
                NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

                byte[] data = new byte[256];
                int bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                string message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data, 0, bytes);

                Console.WriteLine("From client: " + message);

                stream.Close();
                client.Close();

                if (message == "Shutdown")
                {
                    m_server.Stop();
                }
             }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Server: " + e.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            m_server?.Stop();
        }
    }
}

internal class Client
{
    private System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient m_client;
    private readonly string m_ip = "";
    private readonly int m_port = 8888;
    private readonly string m_message = "Shutdown1";

    public void Start()
    {
        try
        {
            m_client = new System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient();
            m_client.Connect(m_ip, m_port);
            NetworkStream stream = m_client.GetStream();

            byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(m_message);
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

            stream.Close();
            m_client.Close();

            Console.WriteLine("Done");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: From cmd.exe try >Ping IP. If IP doesn't work than try the computer name.  You first MUST get ping working before trying anything else.

Comment: Okay, I've tried to ping his IP and I got 100% loss packets. So how do I establish the connection? To what IP (or what else) can I connect?

Comment: Check your firewalls.  Might be blocking.  Also your friend is probably not port forwarding 8888 to his machine on his router if he has one.  Each should open their router to each others IP and port forward to the machine receiving the connection. Turn off port forwarding when you are done.

Comment: If your frined doesn't have static ip/hostname, you will lose connection at some point. Also, if your friend is a server - he should forward port through router, or enable port in firewall.

Comment: I've created a new rule in the 'Inbound' section in Firewall -> Advanced Settings. There I've opened port 8888 for all incoming connections. When I type in cmd 'netstat -an' - I do see the port 8888 -> Listening, but if I run in powershell 'Test-NetConnection <host> -port 8888' - it says that it is fails to connect to this port. By the way, if I just ping this host - its all right.
P.s. Now I'm trying to establish the connection to my Google Cloud Windows Server.

Comment: Make sure you do not have more than one machine set to the same IP.  Either disconnect the ethernet cable from server or turn it off.  Then try ping again.  If you get a response than you are not really talking to the right machine.